# How frequent is high sticking in Ice Hockey?

Tags: officiating, statistics, ice-hockey, nhl

Are there any statistics for how frequently a specific penalty occurs in Ice Hockey? (any League?) I am specifically interested in high sticks.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [this stats page](http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/team/_/stat/minor-penalties/sort/minorPenalties), it looks like high sticking accounts for ~10% of all minor penalties. From the same site, on average there are about 3 penalties per game per team, so you end up with 6 minors per game, so in 60% of games there is a high sticking minor.

Comment: Your information is great and to the point.  However (and someone do please correct me if my math has gone askew!!!), I don't think your conclusion of 60% is valid.  If you have 6 minors a game and 10% are due to high sticking, to determine the games that have high sticking, you'd do $1-(.9^6)$, so only ~47%.  It's because there's overlap, in that some games have 2+ high-sticking events, and so that uses up some of the high sticking games... see https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/binomial-probability-a2/binomial-probability-a2i/v/probability-of-making-2-shots-in-6-attempts)

Comment: That result could be further complicated yet since high sticking events may not be independent.  Statistics is a strange beast that (works against intuition often)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem].  That said, it's not that big of an adjustment, and you're already working on rounded values.  So no big deal!  Good answer, +1 :-)